# bash regex replace index.css in html file

Tags: regex, bash

Going crazy with this. I need to replace index.css in a huge set of html files. So I'm running a sed (in a sandbox).

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $@
do
  isIndex=$(grep -F "index.css" ${file})
  #isHeader=$(grep -F "</header>" ${file})
  if [ -n "$isIndex" ]; then
    sed -i 's/href=.\.?\/?index\.css./href="..\/assets\/css\/index.css">/' $file
  fi
done
```

**Explanation**

`.\.?\/?index\.css.` is covering

- `'`index.css`'`
- `"`index.css`"`
- plus the `./`index.css variant.

The real code is a set of if-else statements. This is a sample file (just for completeness I include all cases in one):

```
<html>
<header>
<link href='index.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href="index.css" rel='stylesheet'>
<link href="./index.css" rel='stylesheet'>
</header>
</html>
```

There is no output, and no replacements. :-(

Can you give me a hand please?

Comment: What if... there's some unknown element like: `<div data-bunga="index.css">`? You want to destroy it's data-* value and take consequences?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, I know. It's a bit dumb code but I couldn't do something better. Any ideas or improvements are welcome. In my case, there isn't any element like that. Though I could always improve the grep, is that what you mean?

Comment: @misternobody : Does it **need** to be scripted, i.e. do you plan to do this often? Otherwise I would use a text editor to do a global search-and-replace of **full words** index.css. Most decent editors offer this, and give you a chance preview the changes intended and skip those you do not want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
for file in "$@"
do sed -i $'s,href=[\'"][^\'"]*index.css.,href="../assets/css/index.css",g' "$file"
done
```

You don't need `grep` to read the file just to see whether `sed` should read the file. `sed` will only make changes where the strings match, so why scan twice?

The real problem is matching all the quotes. :)

c.f. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for great guidance.

Elaborating the pattern `$'s,href=[\'"][^\'"]*index.css.,href="../assets/css/index.css",g'` :

`$'...'` disables all quoting except for backslashes inside it.

`s,,,g` sets commas instead of slashes as the delimiter so we can have slashes in the pattern.

`href=[\'"][^\'"]*index.css.` as the match:

- `[\'"]` says match either a single OR double quote as a character class, but since we're inside `$'...'` we don't want the single quote ending the command string, so we quote that for the command line parser. (`sed` will not see the `\`'s, so I leave them out in the next paragraph...)
- We want `['"]` to be followed by `[^'"]*`, which means "as much stuff as is NOT one of those" until it sees `index.css`, and one character past that to grab what the pattern *assumes* is a closing quote. The `[^'"]*` grabs any path info such as `./`, etc.

`href="../assets/css/index.css"` is just a literal replacement string.

Comment: that's very nice. I have no idea why u use [\'"][^\'"] though, can you tell? then i get you replace / by commas, which is very clever...

Comment: oh we don't need to escape / in the new string slot? that's so good...

Comment: I wanted to explicitly match either single or double quotes as the character after the `=` - do you ever NOT have a quote there? If so we need to edit the logic.

Comment: I wrote all the examples I need to match below the post. It's this: ```href='index.css' or href="index.css"  or href="./index.css" ```

Comment: okey, i'm not saying it doesnt, I just cant understand the meaning

Comment: Why not this `[\'"]index`? That's my problem >__<

Comment: Elaborated the pattern. Feel free to ask for clarification if I didn't make sense.